# How do I prove $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le |x| + |y|$?

Tags: inequality

Only a hint on how to prove this, if not a complete proof, would also be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried to answer this yourself? If so, could you give some methods you have tried in the question, so people can help you better.

Comment: When confronted by annoying roots, square to get rid of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{|x|^2+|y|^2}\le \sqrt{|x|^2+|y|^2+2|x||y|}=\sqrt{(|x|+|y|)^2}=|x|+|y|$$

Comment: The OP did just ask for a hint ...

Comment: @Thomas Well, but I did.  Why did you inform me about your non-downvoting?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I am sorry! I mistook your comment as you saying that I downvoted the answer. Sorry about that! (I of course would not downvote a competing answer)

Comment: @Thomas "If not" means "perhaps even." So I do not see how a complete proof will hurt.

Comment: @LordSoth: Let's not discuss that here...

Comment: Didn't I understand the OP's question? He asked for a hint or for a complete answer! But if you suggest that a hint is more useful for him that's OK @Thomas

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Yes, I think giving a hint is more helpful. Just my opinion. (And just to make it clear: I didn't downvote you)

Answer (score 4):

Note that 
$$
x^2 + y^2 \leq (\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert)^2
$$
(You see this by expanding the right hand side.)

Answer (score 4):

For a geometric intuition, think of $(x, y)$ as a point on the plane, then consider the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0):

By the Pythagorean Theorem, let $c=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ equal the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle with points $(0,0) (0,x) (0,y)$. One side is on the $x$-axis, and the other side is on the $y$-axis. Then the hypotenuse will never be greater than the sum of the two sides. There's slightly more if you want to be formal, but that's how I would set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You might think of the Cartesian coordinates as polar coordinates and note that the trigonometric functions sine and cosine are bounded above and below.

Answer (score 0):

Try to square both sides of the inequality. That should point you in the proper direction.