# Prove $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} \le |x| + |y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logic

How do I prove this? x and y are real numbers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried squaring both sides?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688869/how-do-i-prove-sqrtx2-y2-le-x-y

Comment: Think of $|x|$ and $|y|$ as sides of a right angled triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both sides of $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} \le |x| + |y|$ are non-negative real numbers, taking the square on both sides gives the equivalent statement $$x^{2} + y^{2} \le (|x| + |y|)^2 = |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2|x||y| = x^2 + y^2 + 2|xy| \tag{1}\label{*} $$

Since we define the absolute value on the reals as 
 $|x|= \sqrt{x^2}$

So then clearly ${|x|}^2=x^2$

Also we know $2|xy| \geq 0$ for all real numbers $x,y$, and $(1)$ follows.

Comment: This is the same answer I arrived at but, I wasn't to sure whether x^2 + y^2 was the same as |x|^2 + |y|^2 for all real numbers x and y since we could be dealing with negatives as well. Thank you.

Comment: @OlivierOloa thank you, yes, that was what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a right triangle with legs of length $|x|$ and $|y|$. Then the left side is the length of the hypotenuse, which by the triangle inequality is necessairly shorter than the sum of lengths of two other sides.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Let's try proof by contradiction.  Suppose instead there exist numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > |x| + |y|$.  We then have that $x^2 + y^2 > x^2 + y^2 + 2|x|\cdot |y|$, which implies that $|x|\cdot |y| < 0$.  This impossible (thnk about why).  Therefore our hypothesis must be false and $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq |x| + |y|$ for all real numbers $x,y$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was an interesting take on the proof.